# How would I change my program so that the shape is a triangle?

Tags: c#, winforms

Below is my code, I have already assigned the second and third lines of my triangle a value but am struggling to integrate them with them within the rest of the code. Could I have some advice on where I would implement the other lines.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Graphics graphics;
    int ax = 150;
    int ay = 100;
    int bx = 25;
    int by = 50;
    int cx = 10;
    int cy = 90;
    int dx = 3;
    int dy = 2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(triangle);
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    private void triangle(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        graphics = e.Graphics;
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        graphics.FillEllipse(brush, ax, ay, 10, 10);
    }

    private void movetriangle()
    {
        int newposition_x = ax + dx;
        int newposition_y = ay + dy;

        if (newposition_x < -5 || newposition_x > this.ClientSize.Width) dx = -dx;
        if (newposition_y < 0 || newposition_y > this.ClientSize.Height) dy = -dy;

        ax += dx;
        ay += dy;
        Invalidate();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        movetriangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please read:[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: And that's not a C program. Is it C#?

Comment: changed the tag

Comment: And, you cannot paint a triangle with the FillEllipse Method. Consider useage of three DrawLine ....

Comment: Do you know how I would do this?

Comment: A triangle is a polygon. You can use `e.Graphics.DrawPolygon()` and `e.Graphics.FillPolygon()`. Or use the corresponding `GraphicsPath.AddPolygon()` method. Using these methods, you need to provide 3 Points to draw a triangle. You probably want to add the Points to an array or a `List<PointF>`. It's not clear, in your `movetriangle` method, how the position can become negative.